# Translation for 食べ物を腐らせずに保存する

Tags: translation, conjugations, auxiliary-ず

Saw this in my textbook. The translation is "to preserve food from decay". I get it, but I am not clear about the ず after 腐らせる. Where is it coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-zu is a negative particle. It is equivalent to the negative -nai. kusarasezu ni means "without letting [it, the food] rot".

Comment: Perhaps it would be good to have a comparison of ずに with なくて, ないで, ないように etc.

Answer (score 2):

ず is actually a 助動詞 to make a verb negative. It originates in classical Japanese. In earlier times, 知らず was written as 不知 (same as in classical Chinese) literally, not+know.

Frequently used is 残らず、知らず、せず（する）