# What does 使わずに mean?

Tags: translation, words, relative-clauses

I could not figure out the meaning of it. What does 使わずに mean?

> うちに**使わずに**眠っているピアノが一台ある。

Comment: Your question might be already answered here: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21727/1628 or http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27361/1628 or http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5633/1628

Answer (score 4, accepted):

使わずに means "without using".

The ~ずに pattern is used to indicate absence of an action(since ずに is added only to verbs). You add ずに to the negative root [ない] form of a verb. Eg:

歌{うた}う- 歌{うた}わない- 歌{うた}わずに

帰{かえ}る- 帰{かえ}らない- 帰{かえ}らずに

As mentioned in the comment on the answer above the [~ずに] pattern is similar to the [~ないで] pattern.You can check these links out

[JGram](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=zuni)

[MaggieSensei](http://maggiesensei.com/2013/10/22/%E3%80%9C%E3%81%9A%E3%81%AB-zuni-%E3%80%9C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7naide/)

So, the translation(not literal) of your sentence according to me is-

There's an unused piano at my home/I have an unused piano lying at my home.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: 使わずに means 使わないで which just means "without doing." You can look up examples on the web. It's a combination of the different form of the verb for negatives + に.

Examples:

- する - せず
- 食べる - 食べず
- 帰る - 帰らず

Comment: It means 使わないで, not just 使わない or 使わなくて.

Comment: corrected it. @istraci thanks for that, i had always thought ないで was a command for "not doing."

Comment: The OP might also have trouble understanding what 使わずに is doing in the sentence if they can't parse it properly.

Comment: ^ そうですね、「うちに」が何を修飾するか分かりにくいかもしれませんね