# what is the meaning of いやがらずに?

Tags: translation

So, this is the sentence I have come across:

でも、マルーシャは、少しもいやがらずに働きました。

I understand that Marusha worked without hesitating. I would like, however, to understand the grammar behind it. I have looked for the meaning of いやがらずに without success. Can you help me translate it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm curious how you got 'hesitating'. Anyway, this link may help: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/43100/what-does-%e4%bd%bf%e3%82%8f%e3%81%9a%e3%81%ab-mean/43120#43120

Comment: google translator

Comment: so... is いやがる the verb to hate? So, Marusha did the work without hating it one bit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

嫌がらずに is not listed in dictionaries because it's a combination of several words including an inflected verb.

- 嫌がる: a common godan verb, "to show hatred/discontent", "to hate"
- 嫌がらず: "not to hate", a literary negative-form of 嫌がる.
- ず + に: "without -ing", see the linked question.

So 嫌がらずに just means "without hating" (or more verbosely, "without showing any sign of discontent").